# How to use orderBy on eloquent query with two values of with() in Laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, sql-order-by, relationship

I have here an eloquent query that retrieves purchases data. It has a relationship with tables (`customer and cashier`) and was declared on their models. Right now, I'm trying to get data by `created_at` in `DESC` order but doesn't seem to work. Can anyone point me my mistake here?

```
$data = Purchases::with('customer', 'cashier')->where('balance', '>', 0)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now. I just added `order: [[ 0, "desc" ]]` on my datatables. See: https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/table_sorting.html

It wasn't a query issue but a view issue.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct and it should work.

Alternatively, you can use [`latest()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#latest-oldest).

Comment: Sorry but it still didn't work. Maybe because of `with`. I've tested it without `with` and it works. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please log the query?

`DB::connection()->enableQueryLog();`
`**ORM**`
`dd(DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: Will this be logged on `storage/logs/laravel.log`? Coz I've tried and didn't return anything.

Comment: I've tried removing the `with('customer', 'cashier')` and `latest()` and `orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')` worked. Maybe there's something I need to do on the `with()`? Or I think I need to use an alternative

Comment: Try to use [sortByDesc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortbydesc) `sortByDesc('created_at')` on collection so query would be `->get()->sortByDesc('created_at')`. let me know if its solve your problem or not.

Comment: Sorry, still didn't work.

Comment: anytime dude... @Jumar Juaton